# How to convince Idris in vector length

Tags: idris, dependent-type

Just getting started in Idris (it's Idris 2 if it matters), and stumble upon this problem. I'm trying to implement a function that returns a vector of all the Fibonacci numbers up to given n. Here's the definition so far (it doesn't compile):

```
fibs : (n : Nat) -> Vect (n + 1) Int
fibs Z = [0]
fibs (S Z) = [0, 1]
fibs (S k) =
    case (fibs k) of
        (x :: y :: xs) => (x + y) :: x :: y :: xs
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Can't solve constraint between:
    S (S ?len)
and
    plus ?_ (fromInteger 1)
```

The error points to expression `(x :: y :: xs)`.

I understand I need to prove to Idris the length of `fibs k` will be at least 2, but I fail to understand how to do that, and why it's not obvious from existing definitions. For me it looks like the `k` in `fibs (S k)` must definitely be >= 1, because otherwise either `fibs Z` or `fibs (S Z)` would match. The length of `fibs k` where `k >= 1` must therefore be >= 2, by definition of `fibs : (n : Nat) -> Vect (n + 1) Int`. What am I missing and how to express this in Idris?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `1 + n` is easier to reason about for the type checker than `n + 1` as `plus` pattern matches on the left side:

```
> :printdef plus
plus : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
plus 0 right = right
plus (S left) right = S (plus left right)
```

So `n + 1` in the type definition cannot be reduced without knowing `n`, while `1 + n` can be reduced to `S n`.

With this alone `fibs` compiles. But if you want to check if the function is total, you will get:

```
> :total fibs
Main.fibs is possibly not total due to:
Main.case block in fibs at test.idr:7:10-17, which is not total as there are missing cases
```

Because the type checker does not look into other clauses, it does not know that `fibs (S Z)` is already handled elsewhere. Thus in `fibs (S k) = case (fibs k) of …` `k` *could* be `Z`, and the result then `Vect (S Z)` which is not handled in the case switch.

But the fix is as easy as the first one, just pattern match on `S (S k)`:

```
fibs (S (S k)) = case (fibs (S k)) of
    (x :: y :: xs) => (x + y) :: x :: y :: xs
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! `1 + n` vs `n + 1` is really eye-opening, if a bit unfortunate, as it's very easy to stumble upon it for a beginner like me. I've tried `(S (S k))` already, but without `1 + n` it didn't work either.

Comment: @Haspemulator The red flag is actually using *any* function as the argument to a data type. You should always try to stick to constructors in types. I would consider it very strange to write `(n : Nat) -> Vect (1 + n) Nat`, and would correct it to `(n : Nat) -> Vect (S n) Nat`, which is equivalent.

Comment: @HTNW thanks for your perspective! It's just really tempting to use function as part of type definition, because Idris makes it possible, as opposed to all the other languages I've used before. But maybe it's a good example of a case where "Even if you may, doesn't mean you should", because it pushes the type checker pretty close to the boundary of possible.